# How do I validate that a question has at least one answer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

My question model has_many :answers in Rails 3. I want to be able to validate that each question has at least one answer.

I tried the following code:

```
validate :must_have_answer

def must_have_answer
  if answers.empty? or answers.all?{ |example| example.marked_for_destruction? }
    errors.add_to_base{ "Must provide at least one answer"}       
  end
end
```

I got the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing a string instead of a block to errors.add_to_base

```
errors.add_to_base "Must provide at least one answer"
```